# Тверді приголосні перед «і»?

Tags: фонетика

В різних джерелах, сучасних та дорадянських, зокрема в книзі Ярослава Рудницького [«Як говорити по літературному»](http://diasporiana.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/books/12004/file.pdf), Прага, 1941, сторінка 18, я зустрічав твердження, що в українській мові перед **і**, що виникла зі старого **о** та чергується з ним (*н**і**с – на н**о**сі*), приголосні є **твердими** на відміну від приголосних перед **і**, що виникла зі старого **ѣ** (*н**і**м**і**ти < н**ѣ**м**ѣ**ти*) або зі старго **е** та чергується з ним (*н**і**с – н**е**сла*), ці приголосні м’які. Тобто, *ніс* (на носі) та *ніс* (несла) мають розрізнятися за звучанням.

Особисто я такої різниці ніколи в житті не чув, в мене навіть язик не повертається вимовити твердий український приголосний перед **і**. В радянських книжках я такого не читав.

Чи є така вимова грамотною у сучасній мові? Чи десь так ще говорять? Я знаю, що це норма в русинській мові, але чи збереглося це де-небудь на схід від Карпат?

Comment: Я чув версію (чи навіть факт?), що на початку XX століття на заході України розрізняли два варіанти «і»: більш «м'яке» (в т.ч. з ѣ) і більш «тверде». І вони навіть могли писатися по-різному: перше як «ї» (не плутати з сучасною «ї»), друге як «і» — наприклад див. [«Ілюстрована історія України» Грушевського](http://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/Ілюстрована_історія_України). Але радянська влада з правопису цю різницю прибрала (можливо, частково раціонально, бо цієї різниці не бачили на сході України) — і поступово різниця в вимові зникла навіть на заході (через уніфікіцію письма). [продовжу…]

Comment: […продовжую] Можливо (чи навіть напевно), це пов'язано з Вашим питанням. Але я не оформлюю це як відповідь, тому що (а) недостатньо компетентний; (б) не впевнений, що інформація правильна (в т.ч. опис різниці та твердження, що вона зникла); (в) пов'язане з питанням ≠ відповідь на запитання.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Детально це питання розглянув [Юрій Шевельов](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) у своїй статті [«Так нас навчали правильних проізношеній»](https://r2u.org.ua/node/111):

> ...З ортоепічними нормами української літературної мови, зформульованими в 20-х роках, передусім у працях Олекси Синявського, приголосні в вимові пом'якшуються перед і, за винятком т, д, л, н, що стоять перед і, яке походить з о, а також перед і в закінченні називного відмінка множини твердих прикметників. Отже, для прикладу, в словах тінь, ліс, дід вимовляємо ть, ль, дь, а в словах тік:току, лій:лою, ніс:носа, ясні, горді приголосні т, л, н, не м'якшаться. Це розрізнення твердости-м'якости перед і відрізняє українську мову від російської, де приголосні м'якшаться перед і (в російському письмі и) автоматично. У наслідок цього в російській мові вибір і чи и (в російському письмі и, ы) цілком залежить від попереднього приголосного, і ці два звуки становлять варіянти однієї фонеми. В українській мові і та и виступають як дві фонеми,важлива своєрідність української системи голосних.
>
> У новому підручнику фонетики [Сучасна українська літературна мова. Вступ, фонетика (1969)], укладеному Інститутом мовознавства, питання твердої вимови приголосних перед і в літературній мові, як і питання про наслідки відкинення такої вимови для фонологічної системи української мови замовчано. Тільки глухо згадано про таку вимову як, мовляв, діялектну (с. 183, 254), що, мовляв, "зрідка... трапляється і в деяких носіїв літературного мовлення". Це тим більше впадає в око, що принаймні два автори розділів у книжці – Петро Коструба й Микола Наконечний досі виступали як визнавці розрізнення твердости-м'якости приголосних перед і і що в інших випадках книга обговорює різні підходи до того чи того питання в дотеперішній літературі, – але тут жадних посилань на давнішні писання нема. Отже, можна думати, редакція просто тихцем викреслила небажані твердження власних авторів і так само тихцем заступила їх на власні... Фонологічну систему української літературної мови знівельовано з російською, але нишком, нишком, під загальне мовчання...

Що ж до питання про розповсюдження цього мовного явища, то [«Атлас української мови»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) демонструє ступінь поширення такої вимови (зелений колір) в другій половині минулого століття (коли збирались матеріали до нього):
[image]

[Mикола Погрібний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), Українська літературна вимова, 1992, с. 20:

> *Зубні приголосні* [д], [т], [н], [з], [с], [ц] *і ясе́нний* [л] перед голосним [і], що походить з давднього [о] і здебільшого чергується в сучасній мові з [о] /сіль – солі/, а також перед [і], що постало на місці давнього прикметникового закінчення **–ыѣ**, в сучасній літературній мові вимовляються здебільшого мʼяко: [под'і́л], [т'і́л'ки], [н'іж], [з'ір], [с'іл'], [пл'ід], [д'іб], [н'іг], [воз'і́ў], [ос'і́б], [брат'і́ў], [ра́д'іс'т'], [г´ід'н'іс'т'], [з'л'і́с'т']; [чеꙵрво́н'і], [си́з'і], [ку́ц'і].
>
> Але в багатьох місцевих говорах зубні приголосні перед цим [і] зберігають колишню тверду вимову: [дім], [тік], [ні́жки], [зі́рка], [сіл'], [лій], [д'іді́ў], [сиⷷні́ў]; [молоді́], [густі́], [зеꙵле́ні], [б´і́лі]. Зважаючи на поширеність у говорах такої вимови, вона допускається і в літературній мові.
>
> Завжди твердо треба вимовляти приголосні на стику слів: [моро́з і со́нце], [д'ід іва́н], [з іва́ном], а також на межі префікса і кореня: [беꙵзіме́нːий] та на межі частин абревіатур: [мѐдінстиⷷту́т].
>
> <sub>Якщо проблеми зі шрифтами і немає змоги змінити їх — [зняток](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZkrz.jpg).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Почути таку вимову можна в [Миколи Погрібного](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) "Українська літературна вимова" (1992) ["22 - Зубні"](https://youtu.be/dUrx793sn2I?t=8111)

> Тверда вимова зубних перед гострим **[і]** досягається творенням після зубного приголосного голосного звука неоднорідної артикуляції. Спочатку вставляється коротке слабке широке **[и]**, що потім переходить у гостре **[і]** з тривалим звучанням.

Також у відео Погрібний зазначає, що така вимова є "в багатьох місцевих говорах", але не говорить про її нормативність, та лише каже про допустимість такої вимови поряд з "рекомендованою" м'якою вимовою.

Зі свого боку, [Юрій Шевельов](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) у статті, що вже наводилась тут, ["Як нас навчали правильних проізношеній"](https://r2u.org.ua/node/111) пише:

> В українській бо мові **і** не вимагає обов'язкового пом'якшення попереднього приголосного. Щонайменше зубні приголосні **т**, **д**, **н**, **л** можуть виступати перед **і** і в пом'якшеному варіянті (приміром, **н** у слові *ніжний*) і в твердому (приміром, *ніж*). Історично беручи, твердість зберігається, коли **і** походить з **о** і здебільшого чергуєть­ся з ним, у нашому прикладі *ножі* або, в називному відмінку множини прикметників з **-ые** (напр., у *густі*, називний множини від прикметника *густий* з твердим **т** супроти *гості* з пом'якшенням).

> Такий стан був нормативним до 1969 року.

Answer (score 3):

За правилами сучасної літературної вимови, зубні приголосні, і «н» також, перед «і» пом'якшуються (т.з. неперехідна палаталізація). Згадку про винятки з цього правила я не знайшов ніде на сучасних мовних сайтах. Повсюдно це подається саме так.

У «Орфоепічному словнику» (Погрібний М.І., Київ: «Радянська школа», 1984) у розділі «Основні норми української вимови» п.18 (стор.13) зазначено:
„18. Приголосні [д], [т], [з], [с], [ц], [л], [н] перед [і], що походить з давнього [о] та прикметникового закінчення -ыѣ, вимовляються здебільшого м'яко: <…>. Проте в цих позиціях можлива також тверда їх вимова: <…> і напівпом'якшена: <…>. З метою нормалізації вимови цих приголосних перед [і] з [о] та -ыѣ словник рекомендує тільки м'який варіант.‟

Можна зробити висновок, що якщо таке явище досі десь відбувається за фактом, літературної норми воно у будь-якому разі не становить. Вже у 1983 воно, як можна бачити, вважалося непослідовним, і його намагалися уніфікувати.

Comment: Так от про це я й писав, що в радянських джерелах про це не говориться, наче такого й немає. І раджу вам переосмислити слово «виключення», бо то є маскалізм, ми завжди кажемо «виняток».

Comment: А зараз в яких джерелах про це кажуть?

Comment: Наприклад [ось тут](http://i.tyzhden.ua/content/photoalbum/2012/10_12/04/tyshenko/tyshenko.pdf), сторінка 28, особливість №3, обведена рамкою.