# Навіщо потрібен апостроф перед «ї»?

Tags: orthography

Буква «ї» *завжди* позначає звукосполучення `[ji]` й ніколи не позначає пом’якшення попереднього приголосного. То навіщо ж перед нею писати апостроф, якщо й без нього все було б зрозуміло однозначно? Єдине пояснення, яке приходить в голову, це встановлення одоманіття в написанні апострофа з усіма йотованими буквами, *є, ї, ю, я*, та от тільки «ї» серйозно відрізняється від решти. Мені написання апострофа перед «ї» видається настільки ж надлишковим, як і колишнє написання в російській твердого знака на кінці слів після приголосних, які й так були твердими, та ще й після питомо м’яких *`ч`* та *`щ`*.

Чи є якесь логічне пояснення цього явища? Чи не варто позбутися апострофа перед «ї»?

Comment: Як на мене, у нас взагалі зайва літера в абетці. Річ у тім, що «і» майже ніколи не буває після голосної. Воно буває («інший», «існує») на початку слова — але в цих випадках воно часто читається посередині між «і» та «и» в залежності від діалекту (а в [скрипніківці](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Харківський_правопис) й пишеться як «и»: «инший»). На мою думку: (1) всі слова на «і» писати з «и»; (2) дозволити слова на «и» читати варіативно (хто [і] — хто з [и]); (3) сумістити «і» та «ї» (після приголосної [і], інакше читається [йі] — ну, звичайна така йотована). Матимемо пари: а-я, у-ю, е-є, и-і.

Comment: @Sasha та і-і — і матимемо «і після голосної» — у словах _вії_, _лелії_, _Марії_ тощо. До речі, _виі_ (_виї_) — це дещо інше.

Comment: @brownian, я мав на увазі, що «и» читатиметься як зараз «и» (хоча на початку слова можна як «і»), а «і» в залежності від позиції читатиметься або як зараз «і» (після приголосних), або як зараз «ї» (на початку слова, після апострофа, після голосного). Відповідно сама «ї» буде непотрібна, а «вії», «лелії», «Марії» писатимуться як «віі», «леліі», «Маріі» — ну, теоретично можливо. (Чи я Вас якось неправильно зрозумів?)

Comment: @Sasha це трохи нагадує старословʼянську .) _Дух_ над «и» на початку слова позначав «і». До речі, _дух_ з _варією_ над «и» давав «ї» — як Вам такий варіант?)

Comment: @brownian, я не впевнений, що Ви до кінця зрозуміли мою думку. Я хотів сказати, що з трьох літер («и», «і», «ї»), на мою думку, теоретично достатньо лише двох (а Ви, як я розумію, наполягаєте на трох графемах: «и», «и»-з-духом, «и»-з-духом-та-варією). І я не кажу, що так _треба_ зробити, а лише те, що це, на мою думку, _теоретично можливо_.

Comment: @brownian, а поясніть, будь ласка, докладніше Ваш варіант.

Comment: @Sasha у церковнословʼянській, наприклад, «і» часто (особливо на початку слова) позначали через «и» з _духом_, «ї» — через «и» _з-духом-та-варією_. Це означає, що, з якихось причин (можливо, _нам треба написати словник — сучасний, — такою «нотацією», щоб зрозуміти причини?_) вони на письмі _розрізняли_. І ми _розрізняємо_. Проте наш спосіб мені подобається більше, бо (принаймні, _на сьогодні_) дві крапки над «і» ми давно звикли вважати частиною літери, а не діакритиком. Ви ж пропонуєте, якщо я все правильно зрозумів, розрізняти тільки за _позицією у слові_, що мені здається хибним шляхом.

Answer (score 22):

Це є наслідком реформ правопису. `ї` з'явилось в українській мові в 19-му столітті та цілком замінило старослов'янську літеру `ѣ`. Я точно не знаю, але здається того часу це було зроблено для передачі власного звуку, притаманного `ѣ`. Нехай це вас не дивує, бо `ѣ` промовлялось як `є` в Новгороді, але швидше за все промовлялось `і` в Русі. Тому, скажімо, графіті *...рабу божому Луцѣ*, які ще можна знайти в Софії, промовляти треба не *Луцє*, а `Луці`. До думки, що саме так промовлялось на Київщині `ѣ`, схиляються дослідники історичної граматики. Мені дуже сподобалась робота Л.П.Павленка, "Історична Граматика Української Мови", навчальний посібник для студентів, що можна знайти в онлайні.

Як наслідок, навіть на початку 20-го століття писали *хлїб*, *лїпше*, *цїлий* - зустрічаємо на кожній сторінці в Історії України-Руси Грушевського.

Тобто, свого часу `ї` зовсім не була йотованою, та для утворення звуку `йі` потрібен був апостроф. Лише пізніше за радянських реформ змінився правопис слів, та замінили `ї` на `і`. Чому одночасно не позбулись апострофу, мені не відомо.

Comment: Дякую, так, це я знаю, і саме про таке вживання «ї» йдеться в книзі Рудницького, посилання на яку я дав [у своєму попередньому питанні](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/51/%d0%a2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b4%d1%96-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%96-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%96). Мене ж цікавить саме сучасний стан справ, чому ми досі там пишемо апостроф.

Comment: Мені здається, що апостроф присутній досить логічно, бо він означає йотованість наступного звуку. Те, що ї ніколи не пом'якшує попередню приголосну, ще не все. В слові `п'ять` ні при яких відмінюваннях не з'являється `пять` без апострофу, то чому б не викинути апостроф і просто не запам'ятати, як воно промовляється? До речі, на початку 20-го століття так і було: без апострофу.

Comment: Ви маєте рацію, за великим рахунком апостроф взагалі не потрібен, але щодо я, ю, є там можуть бути розбіжності, наприклад в іншомовних словах. З «ї» ж усе 100% однозначно, те, що воно йотоване, це й так зрозуміло, инакше не буває. Логічні пояснення надайте! ))

Comment: Зараз в українській мові `і` в багатьох випадках пом'якшує попередню приголосну, так як це роблять йотовані голосні (крім `ї`). На початку 20-го століття саме для різниці між пом'якшенням і непом'якшенням і використовували `і` та `ї`.

Comment: @myroslav Здається, якраз навпаки. `ї` використовувалось у випадках, де "дуже пом'якшене" `і`. Ця різниця у звучанні існувала не по всій Україні, і пом'якшене `ї` замінили на `і`.

Comment: Так, звичайно, в моєму коментарі, в останньому реченні `i` та `ї` місцями треба поміняти :)

Comment: @YellowSky Єдине слово, що я знайшов без апострофу після приголосної перед ї - це **суперїжа**. Мені цікаво яке правило тут використовується? 

Чи користуємося тут правилом _Апостроф не ставиться:
<...>
У словах іншомовного походження у злитній вимові: резюме, бюджет, бюро._?

Comment: @SassaNF раджу також [Якою мовою молилася давня Україна](https://parafia.org.ua/biblioteka/knygy-broshury/yakoyu-movoyu-molylasya-davnya-ukrajina-v2/).

Comment: "Супер'їжа" без апострофа - це помилка.

Answer (score 7):

Раджу для початку почитати статтю: [Моргунюк В. Українська мова і український правопис про повновартість українських фонем і та и / Виталь Моргунюк // Вісник Держ. ун-ту «Львівська політехніка». Серія «Проблеми української термінології» : матер. 6-ї Міжн. наук. конф. СловоСвіт 2000. – 2000. – № 402.  – С. 41–45.](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk402/TK_wisnyk402_morhun'uk.htm)

Коротко:

1. > Буква «ї» завжди позначає звукосполучення [ji]

   Насправді, також позначає /**йи**/.
2. > встановлення одоманіття в написанні апострофа з усіма йотованими буквами, *є*, *ї*, *ю*, *я*, та от тільки *ї* серйозно відрізняється від решти.

   В сучасному правописі — так, особливо через значного впливу московської мови, де *и*, майже завше помʼякшує як „наша“ *і*, та *ы* поводять ся подібним чинном. А в загальному випадку — ніяких різниць немає, коли не брати московські унормування. Особливо це було б помітним, коли писати йотовані за драгоманівкою.

---

`Ї` — йотований самозвук<sup>1</sup> до `і`.

**А йотовані відрізняються від звичних самозвуків — попереду `й` чи помʼякшує попередній співзвук<sup>2</sup>.**

Але наразі `і` помʼякшує (для порівняння: московські `е` `и`), а `ї` ні. [Правопис 1892](https://zbruc.eu/node/66463)<sup>3</sup> є найлоґічнішим рішенням.

> Завжди перед `і` **твердо** вимовляємо звуки, які в нашій мові ніколи не бувають мʼякими — `б` `в` `г` `ґ` `ж` `к` `м` `п` `р` `ф` `х` `ч` `ш`: *біг, вінок, гілка, жінка, кіт, місто, пірʼя, річка, фіртка, хіть, чітко, шість*.
>
> **Твердо** вимовляємо співзвуки `д` `т` `л` `н` `з` `с` `ц` перед `і` в тих словах, в яких цей звук чергується з `о`: *дім (до дому), стіл (до столу), ніч (до ночі), ніс (до носа), сіль (до солі), росіл, спосіб; у множині: осіб (особа), ніг (нога)*.
>
> **Мʼяко** вимовляємо співзвуки `д` `т` `л` `н` `з` `с` `ц` перед `і` в тих словах, в яких цей звук не чергується з `о` (де в старословʼянській мові писали `Ѣ`): *дїд, дїйсно, дїло, тїло, лїс, лїд (леду), залїзо, слїд, слїпий, снїг, нинї, нїмий, зїлля, сїно, сїсти, сїчень, сїяти, сусїд, цїдити, цїкавий, цїна.*

---

**Чи твердник<sup>4</sup> надлишковий?**

Так

- Краще переглянути [взаємозалежності](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/) `й` = `ь` чи надлишковості йотованих самозвуків: `я` = `йа` `ьа`
- Твердий та мʼякий — взаємозалежні: не мʼякий, отже твердий

Більшість абеток словʼянських, особливо західних, мов дуже охочі до

- Багатьох [мʼяких співзвуків](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%BD) (словацька `ľ`) чи [йотованих самозвуків](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_orthography#Letter_.C4.9A) (чеська `ě`)
- [Комбінацій](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.9C.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.84.D0.B8), наприклад: `співзвук` `і` (як `ь`) `самозвук` (польська `nie`), що є самобмеженням

Для української латиниці твердник, гадаю, все-таки не завадить.

По суті, це [драгоманівка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), котра зручна не тільки для точнішого відтворення звуку, але й суттєво полегшує відміннювання.

Якщо нічого не змінювати, то твердник потрібний, навіть після суто твердих співзвуків — уникнення неможливості помʼякшення та збільшенню нелоґічності; утримування твердості

Показовий приклад: инколи наразі `щ` вимовляють московським варіянтом (наближене до звуку `ш`), натомість правильно `шч` — так пишуть білоруси й західні словʼяни, тому сподіватись на „запамʼятають як правильно“ — не найкраще рішення.

---

---

Виноска

1. Голосна (див. п. 3)
2. Приголосний (див. п. 3)
3. Руска правопись 1892 року, [Степан Смаль-Стоцький](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).
4. Літера чи знак для твердості попереднього звуку — апостроф, твердий знак
5. [Шрифт](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82)

Answer (score 3):

Протиставлення літер І та Ї з'явилося в [желехівці](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), де Ї могла позначати як йотований звук, так і пом'якшуючий варіант І (тоді як І передавала непом'якшуючий варіант — приголосна перед І зберігалася твердою), відображаючи особливості фонетики, характерні для діалектів Західної України та Правобережжя (*сїно*, але *сіль*). Відповідно, після приголосних слід було відрізняти йотоване Ї від пом'якшуючого, подібно до того, як це відбувається з Я, Ю, Є, для чого також використовується апостроф. Проте, сучасна літературна норма, використовуючи той же алфавіт, орієнтується на вимову діалектів, де різниці між твердим І та пом'якшуючим Ї нема, тому «пом'якшуюча Ї» зникла, замінившись звичайною І, тоді як за Ї збереглася йотована роль (і апостроф перед ним також зберігся).

Answer (score 1):

Гадаю, у вашому питанні вже є відповідь, яка є найближчою до істини:

> Єдине пояснення, яке приходить в голову, це встановлення одоманіття в написанні апострофа з усіма йотованими буквами

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/59)

Comment: @bytebuster, формально кажучи, ця відповідь відповідає на 2 з 3 питань в питанні: «Навіщо потрібен апостроф перед „ї“?», «Чи є якесь логічне пояснення цього явища?», не відповідає на «Чи не варто позбутися апострофа перед „ї“?» — але останнє не є доречним питанням, вимагає суб'єктивної відповіді. Тож формально це таки **відновідь, а не коментар**. Єдине, що можна закинути — що вона **неаргументована**.

Comment: @bytebuster, ну але автор гадає стосовно 2 з 3 оригінальних питань (а на 3-є відповісти неможливо). Тобто політиці об'єктивних відповідей, звісно, суперечить, але це явно не коментар.