# Походження літери Ї в українській абетці

Tags: історія-мови, абетка

Літеру `ї` часто наводять як приклад унікальності української мови, проте у французькому письмі також присутня літера `ï`, як, наприклад, у слові `naïf` – `наївний`.

На сторінці про Кирилицю на [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) міститься перелік сучасних абеток на основі кирилиці, серед яких лише українська містить цю літеру.

Тож виникає питання, чи з'явилась літера `ї` в українській абетці як природній розвиток кирилиці, чи її було запозичено з латиниці?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/60/92) nice answer by [Sassa NF](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/122/sassa-nf)

> Це є наслідком реформ правопису. `ї` з'явилось в українській мові в 19-му столітті та цілком замінило старослов'янську літеру `ѣ`. Я точно не знаю, але здається того часу це було зроблено для передачі власного звуку, притаманного `ѣ`. Нехай це вас не дивує, бо `ѣ` промовлялось як `є` в Новгороді, але швидше за все промовлялось `і` в Київській Русі. Тому, скажімо, графіті `...рабу божому Луцѣ`, які ще можна знайти в Софії, промовляти треба не `Луцє`, а `Луці`. До думки, що саме так промовлялось на Київщині `ѣ`, схиляються дослідники історичної граматики. Мені дуже сподобалась робота Л.П.Павленка, "Історична Граматика Української Мови", навчальний посібник для студентів, що можна знайти в онлайні.
>
> Як наслідок, навіть на початку 20-го століття писали `хлїб`, `лїпше`, `цїлий` - зустрічаємо на кожній сторінці в Історії України-Руси Грушевського.
>
> Тобто, свого часу `ї` зовсім не була йотованою, та для утворення звуку `йі` потрібен був апостроф. Лише пізніше за радянських реформ змінився правопис слів, та замінили `ї` на `і`. Чому одночасно не позбулись апострофу, мені не відомо.

Comment: «Цілком заміноло ѣ» — незовсім так. [Желехівка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), де використовувались літери І та Ї, використовувала на місці ѣ (а також Е в новозакритому складі — т.зв. нового ятя) літеру І чи Ї в залежності від того, чи здатна попередня приголосна пом'якшуватись: *лїки, сїм,* але *шість, білий.*

Answer (score 11):

На додачу до [відповіді Chizh про перші використання «ї» як окремої літери](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/257/4).

За [твердженнями з російської Вікіпедії](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%87_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)&oldid=83570278), які однак не підтверджені джерелами, така форма («і» з двома крапками) іноді використовувалася ще в церковнослов'янскому та «[гражданському](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82)» (початок XVIII ст.) письмі, хоча не мала там особливого значення (використовувалась просто як інший варіант написання звичайної «і» з крапкою).

Якщо це правда, то варіант наслідування нетипового варіанту написання «і» з церковнослов'янських пам'яток виглядає більш ймовірним, ніж наслідування у фразцузів. Тим більше, що, наприклад, літера «є» за своїм першопочатковим значенням є одним з варіантів написання давньоруської і церковнослов'янської «е» — що, однак, не завадило їй з часом набути окремого значення.

Хоча вірогідних джерел, щоби підтвердити цю гіпотезу, на жаль, не маю.

Comment: пропоную замінити твердження на Українську Вікіпедію: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%87

Comment: @SassaNF, прекрасна ідея. Я, чомусь, коли вчора проглядав всі три Вікіпедії, око за «[устав](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Устав)», «[півустав](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Півустав)», «[скоропис](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Скоропис)» не зачепилося, а чомусь за «гражданский шрифт» зачепилося. Треба змінити рос. на укр., згадати устав/півустав/скоропис, відповідно, перше вживання зміщується на XVI (друк) чи навіть XIV (письмо) ст. Там навіть картинки є, і ми маємо право їх вставляли, бо CC. Проте, на жаль, не маю зараз часу це зробити. Якщо відредагуєте чи створите нову відповідь, буду вдячний

Comment: Графічна форма «ї» (з двома крапками) використовувалась у друкованих текстах указів Петра І у ролі малої літери «і». Скани викладені на Гугл: «Копии Его Царского Величества указов, состоявшихся в 1719 и в 1720 годах». У той час ще окрему літеру «й» було прибрано з правопису.

Comment: @Ukurainajin, на Google Books можете давати [пряме посилання](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Ob6OBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover). Це, здається, є прикладом використання одного з варіантів «гражданського шрифта» (що я згадував у відповіді). Але, як я потім помітив за підказкою Sassa NF, є й старіші вживання, аж до [IX](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Файл:Грецький_устав.gif)–[X](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Файл:Грецький_устав_10_ст.gif) ст (ну і ще [XIV](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LavrentyevskayaLetopis.jpg)).

Answer (score 1):

> <sup>Запитник</sup>
>
> у французькому письмі присутня літера **ï**, як, наприклад, у слові *naïf*

Про всяк зазначу, що справдї присутня, але якщо порівнювати з українською, то це по сутї *апостроф*: не є частиною абетки, не впливає на словниковий порядок, вказує, що не є частиною [поліфтонґа](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_orthography#Spelling_to_sound_correspondences) — тут фр. *ai* = укр. *е*, тому теж обовязкове в письмі. Тут ще похідна від **і**, тому **ї** переважно так і звучить. До того ж, в декотрих місцях фр. **ї** може читати ся і як **й**, це особливо помітноо по старим записам назв поселеннь: *Oboïan*, [*Dolinskaïa*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0) ітп.

<sup>Теріторії на які претендувала Українська Народна Республіка на [Паризькій мирній конференції](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_(1919%E2%80%941920)#%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%96_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97).</sup>
[image]

Чого не сказати про укр. **ї**, котра є частиною абетки, впливає на порядок і має [гиншу] усталену вимову: **йі** [або **йи**].

> <sup>Запитник</sup>
>
> з'явилась літера ї в українській абетці як природній розвиток кирилиці, чи її було запозичено з латиниці?

Якщо мова лише про *знак*, то кірілиця, як і латіниця, котра [якщо мова про франційську чи подібну] ще зберегла цю функцію — вказ на самовимову, [успадкувала](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Cyrillic_alphabet#Numerals,_diacritics_and_punctuation) просто зі [ґрецької](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_diacritics). Можна ще згадати про знак — бревіс — над **й**, що теж дійшов до наших часів. Тому, очевидно, зазвичай [писали](//diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:468518/FULLTEXT01.pdf#page=21) перед голосними проти **і**, що є частиною, нп., в **ꙗ**, **ѥ** і **ю**; або там де ґрецізми. З часом **ї**, **і** перемішали ся з **и**.

Якщо вже рїч про *знак* + [сучасний] *звук*, то наразї найдавнїший приклад — праця [*Записки Юго–Западного отдела императорского Русского географического общества*](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/dlib/item/0001358) (1874–75), нп. в роздїлї *Пѣсни буковинскаго народа*, декотрі приклади: *її*, *чії*, *кгрешної*, *білії* ітд. Згодом десь так само вжито в працї [*Малоруско-нїмецкий словар*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) (1885–86), де ортоґрафія згодом стане відомою як [желехівка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) — на честь упорядника.

Якщо мова про сам *звук*, то він міг пійти від **и**, **і** або подібних знаків після голосних або на початку слова, нп. *ѹкраина*, хоча в таких місцях ранїше міг позначати і просто **й**. А також від їтя — **ѣ**, що став **і**, а **ї** — в десь таких самих місцях, як і згадане **и**. Розлогіше про зміну звука в місцях **ѣ** можна почитати [в цій відповідї](/a/1503/585).

---

**Підсумок.** Це точно не запозика з латіницї, бо там **ï** ≠ **йі**, а радше просто **i**, хоча, звісно, при вимові перед голосною в декотрих мовах може ставати. Тож це такий собі розвиток кірілицї. Або якщо копати геть під корїнь, то запозика від ґрецької, але тут нічого дивного, бо вся кірілиця відпочатку така.

Answer (score -2):

Аналогія з французською чи іншими європейськими мовами не зовсім доречна: там умляут над ї використовується для підкреслення, що це не частина дифтонгу, а окремий звук.
Запозичення "ї" в нетрадиційній функції, вірогідно, було спричинене суто технічними міркуваннями: це зараз можна на колінці зліпити фонт, а тоді все обмежувалося набірними касами типографій.