# Чи потрібен апостроф перед "ї" у слові суперїжа?

Tags: orthography

Навздогін пітанню [Навіщо потрібен апостроф перед «ї»?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/53/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%89%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%97)

Єдине слово, що я знайшов у [великий електронний словник української мови (ВЕСУМ)](https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk), яке пишеться без апострофа перед **ї** - це **суперїжа**.

Мені цікаво яке правило тут використовується?

Чи користуємося тут [правилом](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96):

> Апостроф не ставиться:
>
> 3. У словах іншомовного походження у злитній вимові: резюме, бюджет, бюро.

Чи правильно його писати без апострофа, чи краще писати як два слова (Гугл дає й такий варіант)?

Comment: Пояснення одного з редакторів ВЕСУМ таке: слова зібрані з багатьох джерел, не всі з яких академічні. ВЕСУМ щойно виправив написання слова "суперїжа" - разом із декількома іншими, де також був пропущений апостроф.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У вашому ж [посиланні](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96):

> Апостроф ставиться перед **`я, ю, є, ї`**:
>   5: У складних словах, перша частина яких закінчується на приголосний: двох'ярусний, чотирьох'ярусний, дит'ясла.

Відповідно: **супер’їжа**.

З точки зору українських правил читання, альтернативним варіантом написання цього слова могло би бути *супер-їжа* (де замість апострофа використовують дефіс для роз’єднання двох частин), але правопис у [§ 25.4.а](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par25p4a) предписує писати складноскорочені слова з першою частиною *супер-* разом (а не окремо чи через дефіс; апостроф вважається «разом»).

Comment: Справа в тому, що пошук в Гуглі не дає варіантів цього слова з апострофом, а лише: а) без апострофа, б) як два слова, в) через дефіс. Тож мені й цікаво який варіант вірний. До того ж **суперїжа** складається з двох слів, тому, як мені здається, наведене вами правило тут не пасує. Тут можливо підходить правило _5. У складних словах, перша частина яких закінчується на приголосний: двох'ярусний, чотирьох'ярусний, дит'ясла._ Але через те, що з апострофом я варіанта не бачив, тож вирішив, що треба використовувати правило про злитну вимову.

Comment: @Ivan я переконаний, що немає сенсу слухати ґуґл в цьому питанні. Ґуґл наповнюють такі ж самі люди, як ми з вами. Ви праві, треба користатися саме 5-м правилом, тому що тут справді складне слово, перша частина якого закінчується на приголосний.

Comment: Я відредагував своє питання додавши де саме я знайшов це слово. Посилання на цей словник (ВЕСУМ) вже були на цьому форумі. І коли я аналізував цей словник, то знайшов цей випадок і зацікавився чи це помилка в словнику, чи треба використовувати правило, що я навів в своєму питанні?

Comment: яке походження "альтернативного варіанту" написання через дефіс?

Comment: @SassaNF, це помилка. *Супер'їжа* можна писати **лише через апостроф**. [Правопис конкретно неможливість написання через дефіс у § 25.4.а](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par25p4a).

Comment: @Ivan, гугл — не показник. Російське «суперъеда» теж значно частіше пишуть помилково «супереда». Але український (як і російський) правопис у даному моменті чіткий. Тут можна обговорювати хіба що психологічні апсекти (поговорити про прагнення людини до спрощення, про ілюзію розділеності такого складного слова навіть при написанні разом — з якої випливає бажання опустити апостроф (чи «ъ»), про вплив написань «Super-їжа» (правильне), «СуперЕда» (стилізоване) на *супер'їжу/суперъеду* і т.д.).

Comment: @Sasha я там і написав, що правильно тільки через апостроф. А альтернативний варіянт неправильний.

Comment: @Sasha там однозначно написано, як **за правилами**. Якщо хтось хоче користуватися іншим варіантом **не за правилами**, я не хочу і не можу забороняти. Він існує, і ним користуються.

Comment: @Sasha а, я не дочитав, зараз напишу.

Comment: @P.Vovk, перепрошую, що майже перетворив Вашу відповідь на вікі, але як щодо такої зміни? Чи не дуже? Звісно, відкотіть це, якщо погано (або я сам відкочу, якщо не побачу явної згоди).

Comment: @Sasha ви просто дуже любите правила й унормованість. Я - не такою мірою. Але ми, все ж таки, на stackexchange, тому нехай буде по-вашому)

Answer (score 4):

Якщо відійти від правил і керуватися сенсом, то потрібен апостроф (чи інший засіб для роздільної вимови). Зокрема, апостроф ми вживаємо для роздільної вимови, що й маємо в слові [суперйіжа], натомість без апострофа ми мали б вимовляти [супер'іжа] (з пом'якшеним р), як і вимовляємо  [б'уро], [б'уджет], [рез'уме].

Comment: Ця відповідь значно виграла б від додавання посилань на поважні джерела. У тому вигляді, як вона є, це виглядає як суб'єктивна і нічим не підтверджена точка зору авторки.

Comment: я поставив був +1, але зараз жалкую. Якщо відійти від правил і керуватися сенсом у вашому сенсі, то треба також щось робити з `суперідея`, `суперінфекція` тощо, в яких `р` не пом'якшується, незважаючи на те, що за ним слідує `і`.

Answer (score 1):

[Апостроф перед я, ю, є, ї](https://ukrexpert.com/osvitnii-prostir/movnii-svit/yak-zapamyatati-koli-staviti-apostrof-prikladi-sliv-z-apostrofom/) може бути у випадках:

1. Після твердих приголосних б, п, в, м, ф, г, к, х, ж, ч, ш, р: п’єдестал, кар’єра, інтерв’ю, Женев’єва, Донаг’ю;
   після кінцевого приголосного в префіксах: ад’ютант, ін’єкція, кон’юнктура
2. Апостроф слід вживати перед я, ю, є та ї, якщо вони позначають подвійний звук.
3. Після р, якщо він позначає твердий звук: сузір’я, пір’їна, кур’єр, Мар’яна.
4. Після звуків б, п, в, м, ф: б’ють, п’ять, в’юн, м’ясо, жираф’ячий;
   після к тільки у слові Лук’ян і похідних від нього: Лук’янівка, Лук’янчук, Лук’янець.
5. Після префіксів: без’ядерний, роз’юшити, об’єднання, від’їхати;
6. Після першої частини складних слів, за умови твердої вимови приголосного: дит’ясла, Мін’юст, пан’європейський;

Comment: Тобто який Ваш висновок? (Потрібен за п. 6? Чи якийсь інший?)